# jQuery remove not removing element

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a modified `slide-js` file. There are two `divs` that fade and hide on hover that have `anchors` for previous and next.

Very simply if there is only 1 image I am trying to remove them like so:

```
log("removingNextPrevious");
$("div.information-next").remove();
$("div.information-previous").remove();
```

The console is logged, there are no errors yet these `divs` are still in the `DOM` and visible on screen. Ive changing the back colour but that doesn't work either.

Under what circumstances will elements not be removed from the `DOM`?

Comment: can you show your html code?

Comment: Have you checked this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090662/jquery-empty-vs-remove

Comment: Ive just realised these divs are part of a handlerbars template, so obviously thats gonna have an affect

Comment: Is that code executed either in a $(document).ready() block, or included in a script tag after those elements in the document?

Comment: There is only one 'div.information-next' on the page?

Comment: its done in $(document).ready() bloc ready yes

Comment: please check your console panel. you have other jquery error in console. so this method is not work.

Comment: the issue is that im trying to remove the element before its rendered by handlerbars. prob best to modify the template and pass in the count of images

Comment: you could place code after the handlebars .append code, and count the results there, like `var imgcount = $("div.information-next").length; if ( imgcount == 1 ) { ... remove them ... }` , or `if ( $("div.information-next").length == 1 ) { ... remove them ... }` if you like terse code

Comment: Thanks Dom, I just modified the template and passed a boolean in "MoreThanOneImage" works a treat. I didnt notice it was a template as ive just switched to vs2012 and turne3d on dark screen mode

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$(function() {
    $("div.information-next, div.information-previous").remove();
})
```