# Remove table element inside parent TD Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm struggling to remove the table element inside the TD tag using jQuery.

Here is my Table structure:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>some data</td>
       <td>
       <table><tr><td>this table inside I want to delete</td></tr></table>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to use `.remove()` function in ready state function, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i suppose the following will work :

```
$('td table').remove()
```

basically what this says is :

select the `table` , which is a child of a `td` .

so no matter how many tables in td's you have it will remove them all .

use an id or class name to furthermore define what you want to select .

Comment: This would remove all table elements contained in a td, everywhere.

Comment: well ,  thats what the OP asked for  !

Comment: no problem , but please take a look at the other answers .. as they are great way to learn .

Comment: Yes there are alot of options i could use then.

Comment: what if there is a raw text after the td tag? it wont remove the other table on it

Comment: it will remove the table .. but the text will be there

Comment: <table>
       <tr>
           <td>some data</td>
           <td>
           <table><tr><td>this table inside I want to delete</td></tr></table>
           </td>
           <td>this is the text before the table element
              <table>
                    <td>this data should be deleted also </td>
              </table>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>

I tried this one but no luck. the table is still there

Comment: oh i just checked on it. it worked anyway.. i just missed the part.. im sorry.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('td table').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your table an Id like this

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>some data</td>
       <td>
       <table id="tableId"><tr><td>this table inside I want to delete</td></tr></table>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can pinpoint accurately your selector

```
$('#tableId').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you, here eq() are used to define which td you want to remove...

```
$('td').eq(0).find('table').remove();
```

Demo [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/weHdb/)

Answer (score 0):

U can also use [empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$('td table').empty();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbVWn/)

[Difference between using remove and empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090662/jquery-empty-vs-remove)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td > table').remove();
```

this will only remove direct child of parent.